# RTC to GIT migration

Tags: git, migration, branch

I want to migrate all streams with history to new git branch.Can you help me.Is there any tool or any solution simply?For example for each stream I want to create a brach in git with stream history

Answer (score 0):

Found this project in github that can help you .

https://github.com/rtcTo/rtc2git

Or if you not happy with the behavior you can write you own tool with this python librairies .

https://github.com/dixudx/rtcclient